# Using the same TFS build definition for multiple solutions

Tags: tfs

Our TFS 2013 admins have given us one build definition to build our solution and run all unit tests and they are not willing to create any more build definitions. We are following feature branch strategy and would like to use this build definition for our gated builds. I am trying to find how to use this one build definition with multiple branches.

I know, I can add all branches to Source settings and build them whenever a check-in is made. But I want to find out, if there is any way to add branches to Source settings, but only compile the solution that has been checked in. For example if we add 5 solutions to the Source settings, we want to compile only the solution that has changed rather than all 5 solutions.

Comment: One build workflow template or build definition ? Not sure why they would limit the power of creating new build definitions as projects and collection grows. I could see them want to use the same build template for any new build definition.

Answer (score 1):

### You will need to setup an incremental build that only builds the solutions that have changed.

Ideally you will want to setup a build for every branch. You would still use the one build template given to you, but you would define the work-spaces and behavior differently for each branch depending on your needs. However if you do not have that option you can still implement what you are trying to do.

For example if you only want to build the solution that has changed you will set up your build to be an incremental build like the following:

1. In the "**Process**" tab update the "**Items to build**" section to any *.sln or *.*proj
2. In the "**Workspace**" section, select only the source control paths of each branch if setting up a build for every branch or select the entire source if that is how you have to do it ($/).
3. Change the build to an incremental build by changing the Build Process Parameters on the "**Process**" tab - **CleanWorkspace=None**
4. **Tag one of the build agents**, so that it is the only one used for these incremental builds. **Set the build to only use this tagged agent.** It is important that the same build agent or set of agents is used for the builds if incremental builds are to work.

Comment: Are you sure this won't build the unchanged projects again?  I ran a test on the same agent after setting the Clean Repo to false and all projects are built every time.

Comment: @chief7 change Clean Workspace to None and ensure you have a tag on the agent and that tag is set in the build to only use agent with that tag. The first time it will build everything. The second time it will not.

Comment: Ah, I was only setting the clean build to false.  You win.  I like this solution.  Edit it your answer and I will up vote it.  I can change my vote unless you edit it.

Comment: Updated CleanWorkspace=None